# how do I delete all the un-needed temp files in the %temp% folder with batch?

Tags: batch-file, delete-file, temp

Im trying to make a program that deletes the un-needed temp files with batch. How would I do this in one command? Is it possible?

Comment: "_the un-needed temp files_": is there a subset of files in the `%TEMP%` folder that you want deleted or all of them?

Comment: how to decide what's un-needed? to delete all files: `del /q "%temp%\*"`

Answer (score 0):

```
del "%temp%" /s /f /q
```

type `del /?` for help. You won't be able to delete files being used.

Windows deletes files older than 7 days in temp folder automatically. See DiskCleanup task in Task Scheduler.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows does not automatically delete old temp files automatically. I believe you have to schedule the DiskCleanup with the appropriate options.